# CMS page sort order

Tags: magento-1.8, cms, sorting

Looking at the `cms_page` table in the database I can see there is a field called `sort_order` however I can't see any where in the admin system where you can set this. Could someone point me in the right direction

Comment: Personally I liked this question :)

Comment: I think because there is no point where you need this value (at least in CE), there is no need to change it :-) But you could add your own field which should automatically change the value

Comment: The reason for the question is I have installed http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ds-cms-page-menu-hierarchy.html however the order of the menu is the order of the pages added. I wanted to extend but found it extremely hard to believe that a field such as sort_order would exist natively in Magento without functionality in the admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its crazy that we would have to do this as sorting page order should be native but if you add the following code to app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/main.php you can then change the page order in the admin

```
 $fieldset->addField('sort_order', 'text', array(
        'name'      => 'sort_order',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Sort Order'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Sort Order'),
        'required'  => false,
    ));
```

I found the solution from http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/12462/

Comment: You shouldn't change the core code, instead AT LEAST copy the file to `app/code/local/Mage/...` but better add this field using a observer

Comment: Apologises your right, I am a hater of people for editing core files so no idea why I just suggested to do so haha but yes the answer to my question is that you just need to add your own field

Answer (score 0):

I have Check the SQL Script

At First Install script they are not include this `sort_order` in first script verson `install-1.6.0.0`.

when they are update the structure in `mysql4-install-0.7.0.php`.

so they are trying to put sorting functionality at back-end but still they are forgot to implement that.

May be In Magento 2 they are launch this feature.